# Entity Framework 5 - Local BindingList - Filtering?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, bindinglist

Hopefully someone can point out how to do this:

I have a WinForms application that uses Entity Framework. We e.g. have data bound to a gridControl via a repository that delivers a BindingList.

e.g. (simplified code)

```
class ProductRepository {
   public void LoadAll() {
           _context.Products.Where(p => p.Deleted == false).Load();
   }

   public BindingList<T> GetBindingList() {
           LoadAll();
           return _context.Products.Local.ToBindingList();
   }
}

class ProductListPresenter {
    private void SetList() {
       _view.SetList(productRepo.GetBindingList());
    }
}

class ProductListView {
     DeletedButton.Click += {
         (bindingSource1.Current as Product).Deleted = 1;
         gridControl1.Refresh();
     };
}
```

BUT: I only want to display non deleted Products (Product.Deleted == false). It is okay to filter it within the Repository Load() method, but how do I filter it when I already bound it to my control? I can't do bindingSource1.RemoveCurrent() as it would completely wipe the Entity and mark it as State.Deleted..

Another thing to consider here is: I have some other things going on in that form and I need all the changes committed in the database only when the user decides to save the changes by clicking on the "save"-button. I kind of have to work with an in memory state until the user explicitly saves the changes.

Any suggestions? Using EF in WinForms is somehow starting to raise the frustration level..

Answer (score 0):

Because you are deleting logically rather than physically you will need to bubble your delete event through to the layer that has access to the repository or context, then save the change and then detach the entity from the context. Example:

```
class ProductListPresenter {

    private void DeleteHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       productRepo.SaveChanges();
       productRepo.DetachLogicallyDeletedEntities();
    }
}

class ProductRepository 
{
  public void DetachLogicallyDeletedEntities()
  {
   foreach(var entity in _context.Products.Local
           .Where(p=>p.Deleted == 1).ToList())
               _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
   }
}
```

If this is undesirable then another option is to not bind to the context local collection but to an independent `BindingList<>` and then you can remove it from the list directly in your view layer.

```
class ProductListView {
     DeletedButton.Click += {
         (bindingSource1.Current as Product).Deleted = 1;
         bindingSource1.Remove(bindingSource1.Current);
     };
}
```

A third way would be to create an implementation of `IBindingListView` that holds and caches the context local `ObservableCollection<>` and provides a layer of indirection between what the local collection holds to what is provided for display. This way you could use the `BindingSource.Filter` property to provide a filter string.

Comment: The problem is, that I don't want to commit the changes directly to the database. There are numerous other things happening in my form and I need all the changes to be committed at once. So I kind of have to work with an in memory state of my Context before saving to the db.

Comment: @bberger, then I don't think you can bind directly to the local observable collection. You need a layer of indirection to provide the filtering.